# Maximum value of IPv4 TTL

Tags: switch, ipv4

Can anyone tell me if the TTL of an IPv4 packet can be 850?
I thought the maximum was 255.

Comment: i'm curious where you found the 850...

Comment: home work exercise in my book. I 'm gonna writ the question.

Comment: the TTL of ipv4 header is 850.The IHL is 7.what is the size of the data?

Comment: 850 Bytes,843 Bytes,830 Bytes or 822Bytes?

Comment: Translated from German's language.Maybe the question was written incorrectly.Thank you.

Comment: I'm not going to give the answer since it's homework, but it looks like a mistake in the homework question (or your interpretation of the question). If 850 is the value of the TL field (Total Length), the question makes sense and the correct answer is among the listed possibilities...

Comment: Yes a mistake in the homework question.Thanks

Comment: 822 Bytes is the answer.

Answer (score 3):

No , TTL is an 8 bit field so it can't be more than 255